# preposition structure

Tags: sentence-structure, preposition

Are the following sentences correct？
a请你给她带来书。
b请你带来书给她
c请你把书给她带来
These are some examples that I've found in which the preposition 给's structure seems to change,if all of them are correct which one is more naturally used?

Comment: 請你把書帶來給她，請你把書給她帶來，請你帶書來給她 are all acceptable but I'd use 請你帶書給她。This one conveys the same meaning with the least amount of characters.

Comment: Among these, I will choose "C". But personally, I would say "请你(替她)把书给带(過)来".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"带来书" feels weird. When the object of 带 is a single word (1 to 3 characters) we usually place 来 after the object: 带书来. It is only when the object is a complex phrase that we place 来 before the object, as in 带来春天的消息.

给 can be either a preposition or a verb. When used as a preposition it means "(to do something) for someone" or "(give something) to somebody." When used as a verb it means "give something to somebody."

My analyses of your sentences would be as follows. There might be different opinions.

1. 请你给她带书来. Here 给 is a preposition in the sense of "do something for someone." The action is "bring the book", and the beneficiary is "她 her".
2. 请你带书来给她. Here 给 is a verb, to give. Hence there are two verbs in the sentence 带 and 给. This would be illegal in English, but is perfectly fine in Chinese. It's called 连谓句. The subject of the sentence 你 performs both the action of 带 and 给. The object of the first verb 书 is also the object of the second verb.
3. 请你把书给她带来. This is a 把-sentence. It is an special structure that allows moving the object to the front. If we restore it to the normal structure it would be 请你给她带书来. Hence it's the same as the first sentence.

To use 给 as a preposition in the sense of "(give something) to somebody," 给 must immediately follow the verb: 请你带给她一本书. Note that we don't use 带来, only 带 here.